# MVC: Set action name using javascript fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to set the action a form posts to using javascript. I tried to do this:

```
 $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', formAction);
```

and

```
 $("#form").attr('action', formAction);
```

In both cases, the query is malformed, like `this:localhost:xxxx//controller/action1/action2`
Why does this happen? How can I correctly set the action the form posts to ?
The complete javascript function is this

```
function GetNotifType() {               
    formAction = "EditWithDifferentType";

    $("#form").attr('action', formAction);

    $("#form").submit();
}
```

Comment: Just use an html form tag. Do you want it to be done only through javascript.

Comment: How do you define `formAction`?

Comment: How are you getting `formAction` variable? show more code

Comment: try `$("form").attr('action', formAction);`

Comment: @Chips_100, I tried that, as I said; the problem is that it adds the formAction value to the query string, without replacing the old action. I get a query string that specifiec 2 action names.

Comment: The complete javascript function is this:function GetNotifType() {
        newTypeId = $("#typeId").val();
        oldTypeId = $("#oldTypeId").val();
        formAction = "EditWithDifferentType";
       
        $("#form").attr('action', formAction);
       
        $("#form").submit();
    }

Comment: You're not being consistent with your form selector.  Use $("form"), not $("#form").

Comment: Can't reproduce. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/HcAev/).

Answer (score 0):

I used @Url.Action() to get the fully qualified Url for the action, and it worked:

```
formAction = '@Url.Action("EditWithDifferentType", "Notifications")';
$("#form").attr('action', formAction);
$("#form").submit();
```